# How to prove double integral conjecture

Tags: integration

I encountered a double integral property for the Dyson series in Quantum mechanics. The derivation seemed to make use of this property:

$$ \int_0^y \int_0^{x_1}f(x_1)f(x_2) dx_2 dx_1 = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^y \int_0^y f(x_1)f(x_2) dx_2 dx_1$$

I dont see how to prove this, but after trying it a few functions on Mathematica, it seems to hold up. Can it also be generalized to an arbitrary number of integration varables?

$$ \int_0^y \int_0^{x_1} ... \int_0^{x_{n-1}} f(x_1)...f(x_n) dx_n ... dx_2 dx_1  = \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^y \int_0^{y} ... \int_0^{y} f(x_1)...f(x_n) dx_n ...  dx_2 dx_1$$

Comment: your way of writing integrals is really confusing. To you mind reordering your terms to make your expressions clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: the domain of the second integral is the square $[0,y]\times[0,y]$, while in the first integral is a triangle (draw it), subset of the square. Finally, consider the symmetry of the integrand $f(x_1)f(x_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Fubini to show $$\int_0^y \int_{x_1}^y f(x_1)f(x_2) \, \mathrm{d}x_2 \, \mathrm{d}x_1 = \int_0^y \int_0^{x_2} f(x_1)f(x_2) \, \mathrm{d}x_1 \, \mathrm{d}x_2.$$
Then use induction to get your conjecture for arbitrary $n$.